# Laravel construct URL and pass dropdown selected items as parameters

Tags: php, laravel, dropdown

I am trying to construct URL for 'search' method in Laravel, and to pass multiple parameters from selected dropdown choices. I have 4 dropdown lists, and I am trying to pass parameters like this, but it doesn't work, it says Undefined index: country , so how can I accomplish this?

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/search',array($_POST['country'],$_POST['lokacija'],$_POST['prodajaizdavanje'],$_POST['vrsta']), false) }}">  <input id="Search" type="submit" value="Traži" />   </a>
```

Of course I have dropdowns defined like follow:

```
<select name="country"> ..some options.. </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a form, with your input into it:

```
<form method="get" action="/search">
    <select name="country">
        Your options
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

And you will be able to access your choices in your search route

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your form is using GET method.

```
<form method="GET" action="/search">
    Other fields comes here
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

And you can access the input using $_GET['variable_name']

And don't forget the to generate the token or otherwise Laravel will throw an error.